# Merging iOS apps

Tags: ios

I have released an iOS app as separate SKUs for each local language. The reason for this was that a combined version including all local assets (songs, voice over, etc) would be way too large for a single SKU. I have since built a service to provide the localised assets out-of-band from my own back end, and I'm using that for future products with multiple languages.

I can't figure out if there's a way to transfer the existing apps into a single app (in terms of Apple's application identifications) that preserves the existing customers for updates and push notifications, and chiefly the in-app purchases that they've made inside the apps. How would you handle that situation?

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution is to tie the IAPs to a user account in your own backend. Then put out an update for your app to inform the users that the new "unified" version of your app is available and nag them to install it.

It's not nearly as elegant as being able to just have Apple join apps together for you, but it's a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, you would know that its the same app, but as far as apple's servers and iTunes is concerned, its a new app.